# C++ help in loops printing stars

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi there I am new to c++ and i need your help please.
here is my pattern:

```
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *       
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

I tried writing code for this, but it does not give the desired result.
Can anyone help me please?
here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=5,j,k;
    bool o=false,t=false;
    for(int i=((2*n) - 1); i >= -((2*n)-1); i -=2)
    {
        for(j=10-abs(i); j >0;j-=2)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(k=abs(i);k>0;k--)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my output is:

```
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    * 
    *      
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

**Note**: there are two lines with one `*` whereas the desired output has only one line with one `*`.

Comment: What specifically are you aiming for? And post the output here directly as text.

Comment: @Danh No, the output has two one `*` lines instead of just one.

Comment: You are right i have edit it

Comment: Your use of `abs` is a good idea, but you're failing to capture the symmetry correctly by not including 0 as a possible value for `i`. The fact that `i` is -1 then +1 is giving you gyp.

Comment: @bathsheba yes sir. I know I just want your help to fix it.

Comment: Forgive me for being patronising, but that's all the help you're gonna get. Else you will not learn.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should turn up your warning level. It shows some untidiness in your code. I recommend `-Wall -Wextra`. Also avoid [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077) and [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `i` reaches `1`, skip that iteration so that nothing will be printed.

In other words, add the `if (i == 1) continue;` statement to the outer `for` loop.

You can find the modified code right here: http://ideone.com/t96XO6

Answer (score 0):

This is because you decrement your stars with 2 each time and then abs it. i mean. take this example:

```
***  abs(3) = 3 stars
 *   abs(3-2) = abs(1) = 1 star
```

then you subtract 2 again, and the result is -1 so..

```
 *   abs(3-2-2) = abs(3-4) = abs(-1) = 1 star
***  abs(3-2-2-2) = 3 stars
```